# PHP mssql_affected_rows vs mssql_rows_affected

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, sql-server-2008-r2, freetds

I use PHP 5.4.24 with Microsoft SQL Server 2008r2, both on Windows and Linux.
On Linux, I use freetds-0.91-clean. 
On Windows, in phpinfo() the mssql extension says "Library version: FreeTDS"

The function mssql_affected_rows:

- Works on Linux, but not on Windows
- Is consistent with other databases (e.g. sybase_affected_rows, mysql_affected_rows, pg_affected_rows)
- Is not documented on www.php.net

The function mssql_rows_affected:

- Works on Windows, but not on Linux
- Is not consistent with other databases (e.g. sybase_affected_rows, mysql_affected_rows, pg_affected_rows)
- Is documented on www.php.net

Why these two names? This makes hard to have the same code running on both systems.

For future readers, here is a wrapper that I wrote that works in both cases:

```
function GetAffectedRows()
    {
    if ( function_exists( 'mssql_affected_rows' ) )
        return mssql_affected_rows( $Conn ) ;
    else
        return mssql_rows_affected( $Conn ) ;
    }
```

Reference:
http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mssql_affected_rows

Answer (score 1):

PHP is inconsistent in many ways, someone said it has a "fractal bad design" and it's true.... in every aspect and update more and more fails.

For me and many others the order of needle / haystack in functions is exasperating without an IDE or at least a good editor as notepad++ / ST

http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/